# Dynamically delete the table by using parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to dynamically delete the table by using the parameter. I am writing the below code, the code is running succesfully but its not deleting the table. Can someone please help me on this.

Insights is the database name here.

```
    DECLARE @DQ VARCHAR( MAX )

    Declare @DB varchar(256)
    SET @db = @Insights

    SELECT @DQ='
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+ @db  + '[tablename]'',N''U''))
    DROP TABLE ' + @db + '[tablename]' 
    EXEC(@DQ)

SELECT @db
```

Regards,
Ratan

Comment: I would suggest there is something wrong with the process if you have to pass in a table name to drop. If you still want to do such a dangerous thing I would start with the answer that M.Ali posted. It is the only answer so far that is safe from sql injection. I would consider adding a secondary of table names that are NOT allowed to be dropped to protect your data because this type of thing is extremely dangerous.

Comment: quick tip - you can always do something like PRINT @DQ and see what is really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
DECLARE @dq VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @db VARCHAR(256) = 'Databasename'
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(256) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @tb VARCHAR(256) = 'TableName'

SELECT  @dq = '
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @db + '.sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @db + '.' + @schema + '.' + @tb
        + ''',N''U''))
DROP TABLE ' + @db + '.' + @schema + '.' + @tb 

PRINT @dq
EXEC(@dq)
```

Look at how I am checking for existance of object `IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @db + '.sys.objects`. Also in drop you should specify schema name or just double dot if that table is in default schema.  `DROP TABLE ' + @db + '..[TableName]'`

Comment: Hi, i am getting the below error "Could not find server 'databseName' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers." Please help.

Comment: How does @Insights look like?

Comment: its coming like Databasename.dbo.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @DBname    SYSNAME;
DECLARE @Schema    SYSNAME;  --<-- I would add this too 
DECLARE @Sql       NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DBname    = N'Test_DB';
SET @TableName = N'Test_Table';
SET @Schema    = N'dbo';


SET @Sql = N'Use [master]'
     + N'IF OBJECT_ID('''+ QUOTENAME(@DBname)+ '.'+ QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)+ ''') IS NOT NULL '
     + N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBname)+ '.'+ QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

PRINT @Sql
-- exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this code in some other database than INSIGHTS, the sysobjects lookup will fail to find a matching table name, hence no delete.   Sysobjects hold objects in the current database...

Try either adapting your code to look in the INSIGHTS Sysobjects table or be sure to run this code in the INSIGHTS db

It also looks like you are not constructing your SQL statement properly.   Add a PRINT @DQ statement and include the result in your question text above

Answer (score 1):

Seems you missing the database object

```
 SELECT @DQ='
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+ @db  + '.dbo.[TableName] '',N''U''))
BEGIN DROP TABLE ' + @db + '.dbo.[TableName] END'
```

Comment: This code assumes the owner is dbo.   Probably a safe assumption, but just a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, look for the table name under name in sys.objects. Instead of putting + @db everywhere you can just USE @db so that the SQL knows which DB we're talking about in the first place.

```
DECLARE @DQ VARCHAR( MAX )

    Declare @DB varchar(256)
    SET @db = @Insights

    SELECT @DQ='
    USE ' + @db + ' 
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = ''[tablename]'')
    DROP TABLE [tablename]' 
    EXEC(@DQ)

SELECT @db
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing .(dot) between Database Name and Table Name

Try below code it might work for you

```
DECLARE @DQ VARCHAR( MAX )

Declare @DB varchar(256)
SET @db = @Insights

SELECT @DQ='
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+ @db  + '[tablename]'',N''U''))
DROP TABLE ' + @db + '.[tablename]' 
EXEC(@DQ)
```

Comment: I have maintained the databse name in the table itself i.e (Databasename.Dbo.), i have given the dot in the table only. please suggest. Regards,Ratan